# Find $f^{(2015)}(0)\space \text{ of }\space f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find $f^{(2015)}(0)\space \text{  of  }\space f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))$.

I am pretty lost here. The hints say I should use the fact that the function is even, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 5):

Note $f(x)=\sin{(\cos{x})}$ is  even function,
use this well know result

because if $f(x)=f(-x),x\in R$,then we have
$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)$$
Let $x=0$,$$f'(0)=0$$
simaler we have
$$f'''(x)=-f'''(-x)$$
$$f'''(0)=0$$
$$\cdots $$
then we have
$$f^{(2k+1)}(0)=0,k\in N^{+}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What is the derivative of an even function? What about an odd?